# Handling long representation strings

Tags: python, repr

How would you handle long `__repr__` strings? Is there a best practice? Lets say I've got the following.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo(bar={0!r})'.format(self.bar)

foo = Foo(largedict)
print repr(foo)
```

Also is it usefull to add newlines the representation string?

Comment: What is 'long' in your context? And what problem with them do you want to 'handle'?

Comment: @Tichodroma E.g. logging such a class might give me a really long line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) form the santdard library useful.